# How to implement a single FAB across numerous fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity, floating-action-button

I'm interested in implementing a FloatingActionButton or FAB across a number of fragments. When the fragment changes, the FAB's icon should change and the button should obviously then do something pertaining to that specific fragment, however for a seamless display, the FAB is located within the Main Activity and not per-fragment.

**What's the most proper and/or efficient way of doing this?**

I can't wrap my head around it.. I've tried to implement listeners in the Fragment, for the click in the Activity, but it's saying the listeners are  ***Cyclical***

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You can get the Floating Action Button in your fragments e.g in `onCreate` method of fragment by doing something that

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton)this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fab);
```

Comment: Ahh ok, I didn't even think of trying that, of course.. Ok I'll try and implement that also. Currently I managed to get a desired effect by giving individual buttons (per fragment) the same name and linking animations of the buttons using xml like so `android:transitionName="fab_right"` which if I use the coordinator layout view will automatically animate the buttons to relocate per-fragment, giving the illusion of a single button - I suppose this is all that's required.

Thanks for your answer, will implement it then mark correct.

Comment: You don't need to cast views if your "compileSdk" version is 26 or higher. Check my answer.